# how secure is it to have twitter consumer key and secret hardcoded in android app?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm looking at this sample code:

```
authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(BuildConfig.CONSUMER_KEY, BuildConfig.CONSUMER_SECRET);
```

what prevents somebody from decompiling .apk and start using my app consumer key and secret?

Comment: For what it's worth, the API is Twitter recommended Fabric. It's really hard to believe that it's not possible to use Twitter API on Android without risking consumer_key/consumer_secret exposure.

Comment: Agree with this comment and edited my answer below to suit. I think that these tokens need to be protected properly and using a web app as a proxy seems to be used by some (and makes sense)

Comment: i don't understand the proxy solution. how the calls to proxy are made  more difficult to impersonate then calls to Twitter API?

Comment: doesn't look like i missed the obvious. Twitter did: [link](http://arstechnica.com/security/2010/09/twitter-a-case-study-on-how-to-do-oauth-wrong/1/).

Comment: Using your own web app as a proxy to mediate all requests to the twitter api would protect your consumer key and secret, nothing more. I was not suggesting anything else. Effectively it would mean all traffic would need to go through your server. It is not nice, but it would protect your key. That is all it addresses

Comment: in the "sign in with Twitter" scenario i have to call twitter API from the device by definition as i need to know who the user is on device. since it's impossible to do in a secure way, i will not implement it. Sing in with Facebook and Sign in with Google is good enough.Too bad, that Twitter button is cute.

Answer (score 3):

If it is your key and the app is for others to use then these would be available in the app if reverse engineered. Even if you encrypted them in the app and decrypted when using, you would need to include the key to decrypt in your app and therefore a determined malicious user could reverse engineer and decrypt also.

I did a bit of further research on this also, as it kind of bothered me.

My understanding then, is that the CONSUMER_KEY and the CONSUMER_SECRET, are yours and should be protected. I don't think distributing them in any app distributed to a user is a good idea.

Instead, they can be used to create a "bearer token" as part of a supporting back end web app. The bearer token could be requested by calling the appropriate Twitter Web API from inside your own web app, i.e. in a safe environment.

In this way, you would have three actors, your mobile app, your web app and the twitter services. The mobile app requests from your web app a bearer token. The web app requests a bearer token from twitter by making a server to server call over the twitter REST API and your token and secret remain yours. The bearer token is returned by twitter to your web app. Your web app can then store the bearer token in your web app session and act as a proxy for requests to twitter and ensure that even the bearer token remains secret.

Here are some references:
    http://wickedlysmart.com/twitternews-oauth/
    https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only
    http://hayageek.com/login-with-twitter/

Comment: web is easy. the problem is with signing in with Twitter or tweeting from a mobile app.

Answer (score -1):

Prevent decompiling with pro guard tool

Basically, To use a pro guard tool, In your project file called project.properties set following value:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
```

this is a reference of pro guard tool
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Comment: Obfuscation won't obfuscate strings or digits in the text if they are required for use by the app surely? They would have to be stored so that the app code could access them to use them.